# Selecting entities by a list of conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The title is a bit complex I could not really encapsulate what I am trying to accomplish in one sentence. Considering the edmx below:
[image]

How could I select all ParkingRequests that have a RegisteredVehicle owned by a single OwnerID?

1 owner can have many vehicles so I need to retrieve all parking requests made by any vehicles owned by a single individual. I currently have

```
         var entity = await context.AspNetUsers.Include(P => P.RegisteredVehicles
                .Select(A => A.MakeSource)).Include(P => P.RegisteredVehicles
                .Select(B => B.ModelSource)).Include(P => P.RegisteredVehicles
                .Select(C => C.YearSource))
                .Include(F => F.ParkingRequests)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(G => G.Id == id);
```

This query is basically selecting one User entity with all their respective registered vehicles and the vehicle's meta information such as make name, model name, year, color etc. Then at the end I am trying to include all parking requests belonging to this user but I am getting all requests for all users. I imagine it's because I do not have a userId nav property in my parking requests table and instead am trying to retrieve data by all vehicles owned by a single userId.

*ps I also tried doing `.Include(F => F.ParkingRequests.Select(D => D.RegisteredVehicle.OwnerId == id))` but also ran into errors stating I needed to use navigation properties correctly. I am assuming those were due to the fact that I used a Select on a single entity 'registeredvehicle' and not on a collection*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me offer you a faster solution:

```
var ownerId = 1;
var query =
   from request in context.ParkingRequests
   join vehicle in context.Vehicles on request.RegisteredVehicleId equals vehicle.Id
   where vehicle.ownerId == ownerId
   select request;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a lot easier using linq query expressions. I ended up splitting the original query into two with the following linq expression grabbing all parking requests related to any of a single individual's registered vehicles.

```
var vehIds = entity.RegisteredVehicles.Select(P => P.Id).ToList();

            var requests = from request in context.ParkingRequests
                           where vehIds.Contains(request.RegisteredVehicleId)
                           select request;
            var orderedRequests = requests.OrderByDescending(P => P.DateAndTime).ToList();
```

Comment: Downvoted for two reasons.  Solution does not work, and it is not easier using linq query expressions.

Comment: @RobertMcKee How does it not work? Would you like me to take video of my screen so you can see the results? The second reason is opinion. I am the author of the original post so I included my opinion. It seemed easier to use linq expressions since I had access to the object `request` itself. This does indeed work so I don't think the downvote is necessary but thank you for at least providing the feedback and not ghost downvoting.

Comment: I fail to see how your query expression is easier than say... `var requests = context.ParkingRequests.Where(r=>vehIds.Contains(r.RegisteredVehicleId));` as per why it does not work, you are selecting every registered vehicle regardless of user, which is not what your OP requested.  And I can post a video of it doing that on test data if you would like.